# phpmailer fica tela em branco

Tags: php, envio-de-email

Ao experimentar o `phpmailer`, a única coisa que faz é mostrar a tela do `Browser` em branco.

Já alguem aconteceu isso?

Será que posso ter sido bloqueado no servidor de email?

```
  <?php

  require_once('PHPMailer/class.phpmailer.php');

$local_serve = "127.0.0.1";      // local do servidor
$usuario_serve = "root";         // nome do usuario
$senha_serve = "";                  // senha
$banco_de_dados = "GCD";      // nome do banco de dados

$conn = @mysql_connect($local_serve,$usuario_serve,$senha_serve,$banco_de_dados) or die ("O servidor não responde!");

// conecta-se ao banco de dados
$db = @mysql_select_db($banco_de_dados,$conn)
or die ("Não foi possivel ligar-se a Base de Dados!");

    $sql = ("SELECT Nome, campos FROM tabelas WHERE campos < (now()+ interval 10 day)");
    $validade = mysql_query($sql);


    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($validade)){
    $Nome = $row[0];
    $data = $row[1];
    $PHPMailer = new PHPMailer();
    $PHPMailer->isHTML( true );

    // codificação UTF-8, a codificação mais usada recentemente
    $PHPMailer->Charset = 'UTF-8';

    // Configurações do SMTP
    $PHPMailer->SMTPAuth = True;
    $PHPMailer->SMTPSecure = 'none';
    $PHPMailer->Host = '--------';
    $PHPMailer->Port = '25';
    $PHPMailer->Username = '--------';
    $PHPMailer->Password = '----------';

    // E-Mail do remetente (deve ser o mesmo de quem fez a autenticação
    // nesse caso seu_login@gmail.com)
    $PHPMailer->From = '----------------';

    // Nome do rementente
    $PHPMailer->FromName = '--------';

    // assunto da mensagem
    $PHPMailer->Subject = 'Documento';

    // corpo da mensagem
    $PHPMailer->Body = "<body><p><strong>Faltam 10 dias para terminar</strong>   $Nome</body>";

    // corpo da mensagem em modo texto
    $PHPMailer->AltBody = 'Mensagem em texto';

    // adiciona destinatário (pode ser chamado inúmeras vezes)
    $PHPMailer->AddAddress( 'MAILLL' );

   // adiciona um anexo
    $PHPMailer->AddAttachment( '' );

   // verifica se enviou corretamente
   if ( $PHPMailer->Send() )
  {
  echo "Enviado com sucesso";
  }
   else
   {
  echo 'Erro do PHPMailer: ' . $PHPMailer->ErrorInfo;
   }
  }
   ?>
```

Comment: Para que possam te auxliar, coloque exemplo do fonte, como você fez a integração e o erro que está acontecendo.

Comment: Logs do PHP/apache também

Comment: Coloque no inicio do script esse código
`ini_set('display_errors', true); error_reporting(E_ALL);` vai exibir os erros. Depois edite a sua pergunta e coloque os erros.

Comment: Recomendo postar seu código para que possamos analisar o mesmo...

Comment: coloquei esse codigo e continua sem me mostrar nada.

Comment: @user3253195 Recebeste o email que está a utilizar para testar o phpmailer? Adicionalmente, podes fazer um output quando corre tudo bem, do género: `if ($PHPMailer->Send()) { echo 'email enviado com sucesso!; } else { echo 'Falha ao enviar!'; }'` e assim sabes se está a enviar ou não.

Comment: Sim no fim tenho isso. Mas não recebo nada nem mostra nada. 
if ( $PHPMailer->Send() )
{
 echo "Enviado com sucesso";
}
else
{
 echo 'Erro do PHPMailer: ' . $PHPMailer->ErrorInfo;
}
}

Comment: @user3253195 Então a execução do teu código está a parar provavelmente por um motivo que não o PHPMailer, por favor, coloca todo o código, no mínimo desde a abertura da tag de php `<?php` até onde efectivamente tens a linha de `if ( $PHPMailer->Send() ) {`... Oculta claro o email, password e outra informação potencialmente comprometedora substituindo por `****`.

Comment: codigo completo postado

Comment: No from você não coloco nada... olha este exemplo http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12001110/php-mailer-cannot-send-email-to-anyone-except-myself

Comment: Coloquei mas retirei para copiar o codigo para aqui

Answer (score 1):

Tela em branco significa que deu um erro fatal e o script não gerou qualquer saída. Para ver que erro deu, vá no php.ini e mude as opções para habilitar o log de erros e ativar o envio de erros para o log. Veja aqui um [exemplo de arquivo de configuração do PHP](http://www.phpclasses.org/browse/file/5051.html) para ver exatamente as opções que deve mudar.

A opção error_log deve set mudada para ter o caminho completo de um arquivo de log que você possa localizar e acessar facilmente.

Não recomendo que ative a opção display_errors, nem mesmo em ambiente de desenvolvimento, pois ela provoca que os erros sejam mostrados no browser, mas se já tiver HTML da sua página, a mistura das duas coisas pode deixar as mensagens de erro ilegíveis. É melhor mandar tudo para o arquivo de log e ficar olhando.

Em Linux pode vigiar o arquivo de log na shell facilmente com comando tipo:

```
tail -F /caminho/completo/do/php_error.log
```

Answer (score 0):

Verifique as configurações de saída do seu servidor também. Alguns servidores SMTP sofreram atualizações no ano passado e a porta de saída passou de **25** para **587**.